# Laravel Cashier Cancel returns call to member function cancel on null

Tags: php, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Okay this makes no sense to me. the subscribed method is clearly returning true, but then the cancel returns "**call to member function cancel on null**". This should work according to Cashier's documentation. Does anyone have any idea why it would do this?

```
public function cancel() {
  $user = auth()->user();
  if( $user->subscribed('CkWraps Subscription') ) {
    $user->subscription('CKWraps Subscription')->cancel();
  }
  return back()->with('status', 'Your subscription has been canceled. We\'re sorry to see you go!');
}
```

Comment: So the `cancel()` call throws an exception? Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: There is no stack trace, just that error. If I dd out $user->subscribed('CkWraps Subscription') it returns true, but if I dd out $user->subscription('CKWraps Subscription') it returns null, which just makes no sense at all.

Comment: actually scratch that, if I dump out $user->subscription('CKWraps Subscription') right before the cancel it returns the subscription object.... this just gets stupider

Comment: Maybe try with `cancelNow()` instead?

Comment: I did, exact same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is just weird, but I guess it was some sort of strange character encoding issue. Setting the subscription name as a constant fixed it.

```
    define("SUB", 'CkWraps Subscription');
    $user = auth()->user();
    if( $user->subscribed(SUB) ) {
        $user->subscription(SUB)->cancel();
    }
```

Comment: Right, forgot about that. It told me I had to wait some time to do that. Thanks for reminding me

Comment: do you mean that after adding a product in stripe you had to wait some time before it wouldn't return null? So I guess it just takes a bit of time for things to update on Stripe?

Comment: @NitroStoutPlz no, I was replying to someone who removed their comment saying I should accept my own answer as the correct one.